# Does OpenMP 4.0 standard support type-bound procedures in modern Fortran?

Tags: fortran, openmp, openacc, pgi-accelerator

I am working on accelerating our research group's research computational fluid dynamics (CFD) code using OpenACC directives. However, the CFD code is written in modern Fortran and it uses type-bound procedures.

Unfortunately, type-bound procedures are [not supported in GPU code](https://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=6143) by the PGI compiler. My advisor then wants me to figure out whether the OpenMP 4.0 standard supports type-bound procedures in modern Fortran or not.

If so, is there a compiler with this support?

Comment: So are you asking if the standard permits it or whether there is a compiler which implements it?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for your reply! I am wondering whether the OpenMP 4.0 standard permits it. If so, then is there a compiler now which I can use? Thanks!

Comment: The Intel 18.0 Fortran compiler (https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compilers) certainly supports both type bound procedures (https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-18.0-developer-guide-and-reference-type-bound-procedures) and OpenMP. I have no reason to think that you can't mix them, but I admit that I haven't actually tried to do so!

Comment: Hi Jim, I know that many compilers support type-bound procedures and OpenMP, even including the gfortran compiler. The question I am asking is: since I want to use OpenMP 4.x (if there is a proper compiler) to accelerate my code on GPU, and my code uses type-bound procedures as arguments when calling routines in compute region, does OpenMP 4.x support it? I later checked the OpenMP 4.5 API and found many features like "PASS", "deferred" are not supported. Thanks for your answer though!